# Issues -pinch zoom

Tags: android, android-layout, pinch

I'm try to do pinch zoom sample.but itz not working.I think the issue is activity class can't identify the items in xml file.

ERROR Description mapview cannot be resolved or is not a field.

My code as below

```
package pinchZoom.com;
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.nikkoaiello.mobile.android.PinchMapView;

public class PinchZoomActivity extends MapActivity
{

PinchMapView view;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    view = (PinchMapView) findViewById(R.id.Map);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

//////////////////////////xml file///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:isScrollContainer="true"

    >

   <com.nikkoaiello.mobile.android.PinchMapView

        android:id="@+id/Map"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:clickable="true"

        android:apiKey="***MY API KEY***"

   />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Could someone please tell me the way to fix this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    ImageView sampleImageView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);

     sampleImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);

    sampleImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
              view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);

            if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);

            float postTranslateX = event.getX() - start.x;
            float postTranslateY = event.getY() - start.y;

            matrix.postTranslate(postTranslateX, postTranslateY);

            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);

            if (newDist > 10f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
            }

            break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        return true; // indicate event was handled

        }
    });
    }

    /**
     * Checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch.
     * 
     * @param event
     *            the MotionEvent
     * @return float
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
       float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

       return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the midpoint between the two fingers.
     * 
     * @param point
     *            the PointF object,
     * @param event
     *            the MotionEvent
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
       float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
       point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

Please try this.

Comment: Thankz for your codes.But it gives "  java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: My xml filee:-                                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/sampleImageView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: **sampleImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);** was missing in the code. I have edited the code. Please check.

Comment: hi, Thankz for your code.Itz working. I want to use this pinchzoom function to web view. How can i do this..? I try to change this. But "  view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);" not working for web views.can you help me to fix this..